# Hackerearth || rhinoJS || Array Input

Tags: rhino

How read array input in hackerearth or techgig rhinojs editor? 
Please help me to read array of inputs in rhinojs.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mention which programming language you are using.In python programming language it is very easy to get the array input

**CODE:**

```
p=list(map(int,input().split()))
```